# AngularJS routes with Express Server, router is called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I'm new to node and express and I created a simple angularjs + express application where the routing should only apply through angular but the **angular router is called twice**. This is something that i don't want. Also it will break some stuff when i proceed with the development.

Version:

- Angular 1.6.5
- Angular-router 1.6.5
- Node 6.10
- Express 4.15.3

server.js:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
//make folder accessible for the application
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./public/index.html', {root: __dirname});
});
//set port
app.listen(1337);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="page" ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';
const app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('app').config(['$locationProvider' ,'$routeProvider',
    function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        }).otherwise('/about');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl',[function(){}]);
angular.module('app').controller('AboutCtrl',[function(){}]);
```

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong. The html5mode works just fine. When i deactivate the Html5mode the router still get called twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.

The problem was because i Asynchronously bootstraped the application like in this [blog](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data) entry.
He inject angular to get the "$http service" and get some data from the server with it. After that he bootstraped the application.
After i deleted the injection of angular and changed it into plain ajax request it worked.

This only occured with a Nodejs backend. When i have a PHP backend everything works fine with the injection of angular.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html, you use `ng-controller="MainCtrl"`, so your MainCtrl code is called in controller.js.

And you also specify a ng-view in your html so your router is used. You will get redirected to the url '/about' because of the call `otherwise('/about')` and your AboutCtrl code is called.

Remove the `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` and your code will get called only once.